# Send Fraction Keys to Bloomberg Terminal

Tags: excel, vsto, sendkeys, fractions, bloomberg

I am writing a VSTO Excel Addin that communicates with Bloomberg Terminal. I need to be able to SendKeys for the Fractions i.e 1/16 1/32 etc.

I can send 1/2 1/4 and 3/4 as these are ASCII codes 188 - 190.

I have set up a keyhooker to see if I can catch the codes but these keys do not register.

Has anyone else managed to do this?

Comment: Press HELP HELP key to talk with their help desk :)

Comment: Their Help/ADSK used to be good(once upon a time). can't they answer your question? I have heard they are not that good anymore.

Comment: Are you using VBA/Excel to try to send keys?

Comment: Helpdesk says it's not possible. But I think it is! In CharacterMap.exe I can choose the Bloomberg Unicode Font and they show up in there as unicode U+E080 for 1/64. How would I send that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to the problem. It seems that you can send Ctrl+F9 to get a 1/8, Ctrl+F10 for 1/32 and Ctrl+F11 for 1/64.

so to send 4.125 you should sendkeys.send("4 ^{F9}") = 4 1/8
or for 4.625 you should sendkeys.send("4 5^{F9}") = 4 5/8

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Bloomberg once helpful help desk is usless now :)